# How to implement last-in-first-out (LIFO) in BizTalk?

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2010

We have a situation where the latest messages are the most important and the older ones quickly become irrelevant, so the requirement that our new design implement a last-in-first-out (LIFO) pattern for the processing of incoming messages.

So, how to do this? I suspect it's relatively simple to implement FIFO (with the send port's "ordered delivery" check box) but how do I do the inverse?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not trivial. As you say FIFO is fine using an inbound transport which supports ordering and a send port configured with ordered delivery.

However, FILO is not supported in this way so to do this you will need to implement a pattern called [Resequencer](http://www.eaipatterns.com/Resequencer.html), except in your case the sequencing would be reversed.

In BizTalk to implement resequencer you are required to use a singleton orchestration pattern and probably call .net code to implement the FILO logic. Richard Seroter outlines a method [here](http://seroter.wordpress.com/2008/10/09/in-memory-biztalk-resequencer-pattern/) (with FIFO though).

Hope this helps you.

Comment: The following walkthrough post, on my blog, uses this exact technique. Although I need to maintain the order, the OP's case can be solved by iterating in the reverse order. http://maximelabelle.wordpress.com/2012/05/02/preserving-input-sequence-order-when-aggregating-debatched-messages/